# Trying to have a plane have a different color ramp when a spotlight hits it in EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine, toon-shading

I'm trying to get a plane to change the colors when light hits it. I'm working on EEVEE and I set up two spotlights on the car lights. This has gotten me the spot shape I intended, but the plane still uses the same color ramp.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qx8AfD2NQ-g this is my shader setup for the plane, I only added some noise and dots textures.

I'm not sure what to do or what to search for on the internet.

This is my current status

[image: this is my current status]

And this is what i want to achieve. you can see its a whole different color ramp on the lights than on the background.

[image: and this is what i want to achieve]